# Connecting a double pointer to multiple pointers

Tags: c, pointers, tree, directory

In a directory tree (in C) I'm trying to connect parent directories to their child directories through a double pointer within the "dir" struct (`struct dir **children`) but I can't figure out how I would actually associate them syntactically, or "point to them."  A code example would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct dir **children` is not a "double pointer". It is a pointer to a pointer.

To do what you want, you need to declare `struct dir *children[5]` when 5 is the number of children you want to point to, or if you want it to be dynamic, alloc it with `struct dir **children = malloc(number_of_child * sizeof(*children));`

then, simply assign `children[0] = child` where child is a `struct dir *`